# What differences are there between "impact," "effect," "consequence," and "reaction"?

Tags: meaning

When the volcano erupted, the___of the explosion was such that thounsands of trees fell down

a.impact

b.effect

c.consequence

d.reaction

Comment: The impact of the explosion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the volcano erupted,the impact of the explosion was such that thousands of trees fell down

To denote metaphorically the effect of an action, either impact or effect can be used. But "impact" means a physical blow. In case of the exploding volcano, it is, in fact, the physical force of the explosion that has knocked over the trees.

Comment: thank you very much. could you explain why you use this word?

Comment: Hope I answered...

Comment: Yes, I see, thank you, but why we don't use the word "consequence"